# boto .get_all_keypairs() method and the .save() of its results

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

So I have access to a number of EC2 instances, some of which have been running for years.  We have a special repository of the private keys to all of these; thus I can, for most of our instances, get into them as root (or the 'ubuntu' user in some cases) to administer them.

While playing with boto I noticed the EC2 .get_keypair() and get_all_keypairs methods and was wondering if this could be used to recover any SSH keys which have slipped through the cracks of our procedures and been lost.

When I inspect the resulting boto.ec2.keypair.KeyPair objects, however, I see that the .material attribute seems to be empty and when I try to use the keypair's .save() method I get an exception complaining that the materials haven't been fetched.

(Other operations, such as .get_all_instances() and .run_instances() are working during that session).

So, what am I missing?  Are there some other operations for which I have to provide the X.509 cert. in addition to my normal AWS key/secret pair?

(Note: I don't actually need this yet.  I'm just familiarizing myself with the API and preparing for such eventualities).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to recover SSH keys like so, the [get_all_key_pairs()](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_all_instances) method name is a bit misleading in this regard, though properly documented by means of the return object of class [boto.ec2.keypair.KeyPair](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.keypair.KeyPair) at least, see e.g. the [save()](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.keypair.KeyPair.save) method:

> Save the material (the unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key) of a
>   **newly created KeyPair** to a local file. *[emphasis mine]*

This is not a limitation of [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto), but a result of the security architecture of [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/): you can only retrieve a complete key pair (i.e. including the private key) during the initial creation of a key pair, the private key is never stored by EC2 and cannot be recovered, if you ever loose it (but see below for a workaround).

Eric Hammond's recent answer to the related question [consequences of deleted key pair on ec2 instance](https://serverfault.com/a/382137/10305) provides another angle to this topic, including a pointer to his article [Fixing Files on the Root EBS Volume of an EC2 Instance](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root), explaining how to get access to the instance regardless eventually.

Given some of your instances *have been running for years*, this might not work though, insofar     *This process is only available with an EBS boot instance* (which haven't been available back then), and, as Eric stresses as well, is one of the many reasons why [You Should Use EBS Boot Instances on Amazon EC2](http://alestic.com/2012/01/ec2-ebs-boot-recommended) nowadays.