# Create new EC2 keypair on AWS with Boto3

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

The boto3 1.1.2 docs [say that the `create_key_pair` command](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_key_pair) is supposed to return a dict containing the private key of the newly created keypair.

I am indeed using that version…

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.1.2'
```

…yet when I run `create_key_pair` I am instead returned a [`KeyPair` object](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.KeyPair) which does not appear to contain any information about the private key.  The keypair does get created, it's just that I have no way of retrieving the private key because [it is only ever available at the time of the keypair's creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10570808/334517).  Older boto APIs apparently had a `.save` method on the `KeyPair` object to save the key to a file, but that too appears to have been removed from the API.

**In boto3 1.1.2, how does one create a new EC2 keypair *and* retrieve its private key?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The private key is available in `keypair['KeyMaterial']`:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
>>> keypair = ec2.create_key_pair(KeyName='foo')
>>> keypair['KeyMaterial']
'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpAIBAAKCA...\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

References:

- [boto3 `create_key_pair()` documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?#EC2.Client.create_key_pair)
- [boto3 EC2 migration guide](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html)

Comment: My problem was that I was using `ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')` instead of a client, and the resource implementation of `create_key_pair` apparently has a different API.  I solved it by switching to `keypair = ec2.meta.client.create_key_pair(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

In the new versions of boto3 (I'm using 1.4.7) change this line:

```
keypair['KeyMaterial']
```

to

```
keypair.key_material
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the feature to save to local keypair file

```
$ cat keypair.py

import boto3

keypair_name = "python_keypair"

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
keypair = ec2.create_key_pair(KeyName=keypair_name)

private_key_file=open(keypair_name,"w")
private_key_file.write(response['KeyMaterial'])
private_key_file.close
```

now you should get the private key locally

```
$ cat python_keypair.pem

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA14D9GAC7zVSRr3iHUyEaIF8ol5ccWBj9InVqYnF28l10EUCz
g5OLL5Ll6WiIYvlxhcRHM5d0os2Lg5SuKi0mTktYQ7QVD8RkdoEYIVrqgBir3VMf
8jG08JRhaJs4/OQk2+WAGecjcVx6joz9yXTRT3Maaec/4qNigfYMLpSsdAoZ0hrk
....
```

move it to `~/.ssh` and change permission to 600